# How to access entity manager with spring boot and spring data

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

How can I get access to the `Entity Manager` in the repository when using Spring Boot and Spring Data?

Otherwise, I will need to put my big query in an annotation. I would prefer to have something more clear than a long text.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You would define a `CustomRepository` to handle such scenarios. Consider you have `CustomerRepository` which extends the default spring data JPA interface `JPARepository<Customer,Long>`

Create a new interface `CustomCustomerRepository` with a custom method signature.

```
public interface CustomCustomerRepository {
    public void customMethod();
}
```

Extend `CustomerRepository` interface using `CustomCustomerRepository`

```
public interface CustomerRepository extends JpaRepository<Customer, Long>, CustomCustomerRepository{

}
```

Create an implementation class named `CustomerRepositoryImpl` which implements `CustomerRepository`. Here you can inject the `EntityManager` using the `@PersistentContext`. Naming conventions matter here.

```
public class CustomCustomerRepositoryImpl implements CustomCustomerRepository {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    @Override
    public void customMethod() {
    
    }
}
```

Comment: CustomerRepositoryImpl class should implement CustomCustomerRepository  not CustomerRepository as only method of CustomCustomerRepository  needs implementation

Comment: Does this CustomCustomerRepositoryImpl work without a customMethod()?

Comment: I am getting this error `No property customMethod found for type Customer` do I need to do any configuration ?

Comment: If you get error "No property customMethod found for type Customer" remove annotation @PersistenceContext and inject the entityManager object via the constructor of CustomRepositoryImpl

Comment: @cnmuc can you elaborate on the solution you mentioned. I am facing the same issue as you mentioned.

Comment: @AvikAggarwal public class CustomerRepositoryImpl implements CustomCustomerRepository {

    private final EntityManager entityManager;

    public CustomerRepositoryImpl(EntityManager entityManager) {
        this.entityManager = entityManager;
    }
 
}

Comment: Thanks @cnmuc. I had implemented that but now I face `No query defined for that name`. Any idea about this?
Please note I am using a query to transform my table data to another shape defined as DTO.

Comment: Spring Data JPA Reference - https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.custom-implementations

Comment: Convoluted answer and doesn't work. What do we even inject to our main class? the Impl or Repository class? both ways I'm still getting the same error - Also - I have a JPA method on the `extends JpaRepository<>` interface that I need to use

Comment: Does CustomCustomerRepositoryImpl need to have annotation @Repository

Comment: I think using the `Customer` entity as an example was a bad choice. I got confused with all the custom customer stuff.

Answer (score 3):

In case you have many repositories to deal with, and your need in `EntityManager` is not specific for any particular repository, it is possible to implement various `EntityManager` functionality in a single helper class, maybe something like that:

```
@Service
public class RepositoryHelper {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    @Transactional
    public <E, R> R refreshAndUse(
            E entity,
            Function<E, R> usageFunction) {
        em.refresh(entity);
        return usageFunction.apply(entity);
    }

}
```

The `refreshAndUse` method here is a sample method to consume a detached entity instance, perform a refresh for it and return a result of a custom function to be applied to the refreshed entity in a declarative transaction context. And you can add other methods too, including query ones...