# Custom Query in springData Jpa

Tags: spring-boot, microservices

I have multiple Columns for a home address such as 
CommHouseNo
CommStreetNo
CommLandMark
CommVillCity
CommDistrict
CommState
CommTelephone
CommPinCode

now I want to return the whole value in one single line. I have a query with me but how to return this using springBoot Data JPA

Comment: Please add your query and table entity structure in question for better understanding

Comment: Does this answer your question? 
  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42966967/creating-a-custom-query-with-spring-data-jpa