# Spring JPA select single column with count limit

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I want to fetch id from my table with count limit=1.

What I tried?

```
Optional<Long> findFirstIdByServiceSeeker_Id(Long serviceSeekerId); // But it returns Entity. I need id alone
```

**I have following solution to fix it, but I want to know how to fetch id along with limit?**

**Alternate solution:**

```
 Optional<User> findFirstIdByServiceSeeker_Id(Long serviceSeekerId); 
 Optional<User> userOptional =  userRepository.findFirstIdByServiceSeeker_Id(serviceSeekerId);
 Long userId =userOptional.get().getId();// it will fix
```

Answer (score 0):

in jpa u can make it as follow ,

```
Optional<CustomType> findFirstIdByServiceSeeker_Id(Long serviceSeekerId);




public interface CustomType {
    getId();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try writing custom Query like this!** *(Modify as per the DB/SQL Conventions)*

```
@Query("SELECT serviceSeekerId from USERS u where u.serviceSeekerId= :serviceSeekerId")

Long findFirstIdByServiceSeekerId(String id);
```

Refer similar links

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-query

[Creating a custom query with Spring DATA JPA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42966967/creating-a-custom-query-with-spring-data-jpa)

Comment: Yes. I tried exact same query. Problem is it return list of ids. Because serviceSeekerId is not unique. I want to limit the results to 1.