# How to use Custom Query with spring boot data jpa

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to create a web application using spring boot. My persistent data is stored on PostgreSQL database. However, I need to use elasticsearch for Full Text Search. (I know there is postgres Full text search but I need elastic). For this purpose I'm using  [zombodb](https://github.com/zombodb/zombodb). This is an extension of Postgres that allows postgres and ElasticSearch to work together. But it has its own sql  [syntax](https://github.com/zombodb/zombodb/blob/master/TUTORIAL.md). Example of a full text search:

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE products ==> 'sports or box'
```

When I use directly this query, it works. However, when I want to use native query with parameter like

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE products ==> :searched
```

it gives "operator does not exist: products ==> character varying" error. 
İs there any solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Query annotation did not work for me. I was able to implement [this soulution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30874214/how-to-access-entity-manager-with-spring-boot-and-spring-data), working quite fine.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in our project we also use an extension of postgresql (POSTGIS).
In our case we used native query of JPA directly, and even postgis specific methods works perfectly. So I suggest you to use native query support.

Here is an example:

```
public interface ProductRepository extends JpaRepository<Product,Long>{
    @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE products ==> 'sports or box'", nativeQuery=true)
    List<Product> someFancyMethodName();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately I tried this but did not work. I guess even native queries are kind of parsed and interpreted, so it gives something like sql syntax error (I don't remember the whole error, when I get to home, I'll edit here)